# Delay AWS Code Pipeline:

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

Current Setup:
I have a Lambda function that is invoked by AWS CodePipeline. The Lambda function dumps some files to a s3 bucket and the CodePipeline continues on to another phase (in this case a testing phase).

Problem:
I need the aforementioned pipeline to wait around 60 seconds after the files are dumped to the s3 bucket (this is to ensure processing has finished within my code base that reads the s3 bucket that was dumped to). After the delay, my tests should execute cleanly.

Question:
Is there a way within code pipeline to wait for a given time?
Could Lambda execute a waiting function?

-

I have done a fair amount of research on implementing delays in Javascript (the language that my Lambda function is written in). I couldn't implement an async sleep function, nor could I find any Lambda documentation on how this is implemented.

Comment: Is it feasible to do this with two pipelines instead?

Comment: Is it possible for your Lambda function to know when your application has finished processing the files and wait? Eg. do you have a "ListProcesses" API you can call to see when it's done? The advantage of explicitly checking when your application has finished processing is that the length of time you wait will change dynamically even if your processing becomes faster or slower over time due to functionality changes.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I am failing to see the error handling operations here. Imagine that an application fails to process and the files remain in the bucket in which they were supposed to be removed. The application would ideally time out after a minute or so... Thus introducing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about JS lambda , but from your JS lambda you can call another Lamda written in Python to wait for 60 sec.

Second approach could be you can use AWS step function to wait for 60 sec after you dump the data in S3 and before you execute the test method.

Python Lambda to wait:

```
import boto3, os, time
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: I like this answer, but it is certainly not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can implement a timeout function as it follows:

```
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function play() {
    console.log('Hello');
    await timeout(2000);
    console.log(' world!');
}

play();
```

So you can wait like this in your lambda function. I do not know about anything like a 'wait' like step in AWS CodePipeline, and it is also pointed out [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=282896) that this is natively not supported.

Answer (score 0):

With AWS Step Functions Integration - you have the option to wait for longer period of times as well, the Lambda max timeout is 15 minutes - with Step Function this period can be extended much longer (1 year) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits-overview.html